# jQuery text limiter /r/n issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am using jQuery text limiter on client http://rustyjeans.com/jquery-plugins/input-limiter side + mvc validation

```
$('#text').inputlimiter({ limit: 10 });
[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be {1} characters or less")]
```

But if i set for example 10 and then type

```
a(enter)
aaa(enter)
aaaa
```

Clien validation says OK, but after i submit the form i getting server validation error that message more than 10 chars length.

Anything i can do with that?

Is there any limit plugins witch would be compatible with asp.net mvc 3.0?